# Visual Studio C# zoneidentifier.cxx The system cannot find the file specified && Rejecting native image because native image dependency

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2017 Console Output shows me

> onecoreuap\inetcore\urlmon\zones\zoneidentifier.cxx(359)\urlmon.dll!6F1D6037: (caller: 6F1D6F68) ReturnHr(1) tid(24e0) 80070002 cannot find the file specified.

---

> onecoreuap\inetcore\urlmon\zones\zoneidentifier.cxx(359)\urlmon.dll!6F1D6037: (caller: 6F1D6F68) ReturnHr(2) tid(24e0) 80070002 cannot find the file specified.

---

> CLR:(C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll) Rejecting native image because native image dependency C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll had a different identity than expected

---

> CLR:(C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll) Rejecting native image because native image dependency C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll had a different identity than expected

---

> IMGSF01-DLL_PROCESS_ATTACHC:\WINDOWS\system32\ImgsfProcPolicyForExe.xmlException thrown at 0x76E608C2 (KernelBase.dll) in application.exe: 0x000006BA: RPC Server Unavailable

---

I want to know what those outputs are meaning and how to solve it.
Currently application looks working fine. However, I should make it sure before release application to market.

**My application depends on .NET Framework 4.5.2 and Winform.**

Comment: Did you ever find a reason for this?  I am getting the same error with .NET FrameWork 4.7 and using WPF, not Winforms.

Comment: Sorry @Joe, I still does not know what cause this...